# Execute delete queries using batch file?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, cmd

I am using Oracle11g. I have below two sql queries.

```
Delete from TableA;
Delete from TableB;
Delete from TableC;
Delete from TableD;
Delete from TableE;
```

Now how can i create a batch file to run this script By passing the credentials to connect to DB and delete using above queries?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the above queries are just sample. Still `TRUNCATE` is the best option to delete the entire content of table. (Unless, a `ROLLBACK` is not needed)

Answer (score 1):

Add the statements to a file, say "delete.sql".
To execute the statements in the file, type:

```
sqlplus username/password@tns_name_of_your_db @delete.sql
```

...or simply add that into a .BAT file.

PS. Remember to add a `COMMIT;` statement.

PS2. Make sure the last line of "delete.sql" is empty (blank line).

Comment: Ronnis, can this batch file be run on any machine? Or does the machine should have any software installed? Because i have to do it to delete in remote database..

Comment: You need Oracle Client to run SQL*Plus.